# Output redirect in shell to another file iff the file exist

Tags: linux, shell, unix, redirect

I am using the following command to redirect the output to another file.

```
ls -l >>foo.txt
```

This command will append the output of `ls -l` to foo.txt. And if the file does not exist it will create a new file foo.txt and redirect the output to new foo.txt.

Now **is there any way to redirect/append the output of `ls -l` to a file if it and only if the file already exist and otherwise it won't redirect the output or will discard it**.

For my case if the foo.txt already exist it will append the output to foo.txt otherwise it will discard the output.

Is there any command to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tests if `foo.txt` exists and is a regular file before running the `ls -l >> foo.txt` command:

```
test -f foo.txt && ls -l >> foo.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ls -l |
    if [ -f "$file" ]
        then cat >> "$file"
        else cat # or whatever you want to do with the output
    fi
```

Note that the operation is not atomic: it is possible to unlink the file after its existence is checked and before it's opened for writing.

Comment: +1 for mentioning atomicity...and for proper use of "it's" and "its"!

Answer (score 4):

Don't know any built-in syntax to do it but something like the following should work:

```
if [ -f foo.txt ] ; then
  out=foo.txt
else
  out=/dev/null
fi
ls -l >> $out
```